# Is it possible to combine Morris.js (RaphaelJS) with Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, dom, raphael, web-worker, morris.js

I'm trying to use Web Workers to improve the performance of my website, which generates graphs using the library Morris (which in turn uses Raphael). The problem is that Morris manipulates the DOM (not much, just to pass the div where the graph is drawn). I understand that Web Workers do not allow you to manipulate the DOM. Someone has tried to combine these two elements (Morris -or Raphael- and Web Workers)?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael itself creates the SVG nodes in the DOM which is the bigger issue. I am also seaching for way to let the time consuming rendition of complex stuff in a worker.